# select most recently added record with value in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a table with the following structure

```
CREATE TABLE `data` (
  `type` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `subscr_id` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL
)
```

In this table, there are many records with `subscr_id` of `id100`. I would like to select a record with `subscr_id` of `id100`, that was added to the table most recently.

How can I do that?

Comment: You start with having a primary key. Or a date column. You don't create a 2 column table and expect the system to give you "the latest" one with literally 0 information available to conclude which one is the latest.

Comment: You can not select it, because you have no time, when the record is added

Comment: You need either the creation time or an auto-incremented column to specify the order of inserts.

Comment: You should add a timestamp column ideally or at least a primary key column.

Comment: okay, so I create another column called auto_incr and autoincrement it. Than i select id100 with the highest auto_incr. Is this the way to go?

Comment: @lalithkumar he doesn't have to add both columns. Could you please stop posting wrong comments? Primary key is **enough** on its own **OR** timestamp/datetime field. Primary key is a better choice. There can be both. It's not **mandatory** to have both.

Comment: @GordonLinoff But if table already exists, and we need to find a row in this table without auto-incremented primary key and without created_at field... There must be some solution...

Comment: @VladimirKovpak there isn't. You use columns designed to give you that information. You don't rely on magic. MySQL will create a hidden primary key in this instance, but it won't let you use it in any way as it uses it for its internal purposes (the order of insertion etc.). If you create a table like this one, you made a mistake and you fix your mistake. You don't try to hack your way through.

Comment: @Mjh Totally disagree. I've not created this table, it is not my fault. But I need to find correct row, and I sure it is possible!!! For example, `nhuyminh` answer works correctly.

Comment: @Mjh But in general, I agree about auto-incremented primary key or created_at field. But it's must be done on design stage. If it's design stage - great, if not - need to consider another options...

Comment: @VladimirKovpak I'm not saying **YOU** personally created the table, I'm using `you` as a general term. And no, it is not possible. The answer you quoted works because primary key has been added to the table. If you don't have the date, timestamp or primary key then you can't find the latest record.

Comment: @Mjh But it is possible!) Example in my answer works also, and it is because of that fact that mysql always have primary key (implicit or explicit),  and you've writen it)

Answer (score 2):

You add an ID - Indentify column. It's best performance in this/your situation.

```
ALTER TABLE data ADD COLUMN id INT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT FIRST, ADD KEY(id);
```

Run the below SQL, you will receive the record with subscr_id of id100, that was added to the table most recently most recently.

```
SELECT * FROM `data` WHERE subscr_id = 'id100' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: In case the author of question consider the opportunity to alter table - I think it is the best answer!)

Answer (score -1):

I think you have to improve your table design and add auto-inctemental `primary key` or `created_at` field.
But if you can't do it or you need run query just once, you can try this approach (it's a bit tricky but it works ).

In general recent record will be present at the end of the table. For example we have table like this:

```
+------+-----------+
| type | subscr_id |
+------+-----------+
| a    | id100     |
| b    | id100     |
| c    | id100     |
| a    | id200     |
| b    | id200     |
| d    | id100     |
| c    | id200     |
| e    | id100     |
+------+-----------+
```

And here wee need calculate total count of interesting rows and use it for offset, like this:

```
set @offset = (select count(*) from data where subscr_id = 'id100') - 1;
set @sql = concat(
    "select * from data where subscr_id = 'id100' limit 1 offset ",
    @offset
);
prepare stmt1 from @sql;
execute stmt1;
```

The result will look like this:

```
+------+-----------+
| type | subscr_id |
+------+-----------+
| e    | id100     |
+------+-----------+
```